# Math methods (powers)

Tags: java, math

I've been having trouble writing a math function. It is supposed to take in 3 variables and compute the equation like so.

answer = x(1 + y/100)^ z

I have it written as:

```
public compute_cert (int years, double amount, double rate)
{
certificate = amount * pow(1 + rate/100, years);
return certificate;
}
```

I am also to return the certificate (answer) amount but I get this error:

```
CDProgram.java:54: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
public compute_cert (int years, double amount, double rate)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do exactly what the error message tells you to do -- insert a return type in the method declaration line.

Comment: What type do you expect `compute_cert` to return?

Comment: You also haven't specified a type for certificate... add that, and declare your method's return type to match that. (presumably double)

Comment: yep, figured that piece out. Any idea what to do for the math part? Im not so good with math programming. Haven't had much practice with it

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "for the math part"? edit: nevermind, I assume you meant Math.pow as others have said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a lot of types: That of the local variable `certificate` and the type in the method header. You also need to say `Math.pow` instead of just `pow`, or it doesn't know what `pow` method you're talking about. Your math is right.

```
public double compute_cert (int years, double amount, double rate)
{
    double certificate = amount * Math.pow(1 + rate/100, years);
    return certificate;
}
```

Comment: Ive tried to use this but have only gotten certificate to come out to 0.0. I even changed the return type to void and changed the return certificate to print.ln certificate and still no luck. what do you think might be the problem?

Comment: Did you check the input values? Are they what they are expected to be?

Comment: all imputs are at least greater than 10. should be good there

Comment: The compiler should automatically cast `years` up to a `double`, you can try adding that and seeing if it'll help. More specifically, change `years` in the formula to `(double) years`.

Comment: Are you checking your input values inside the `compute_cert` method? That's where you need to check to see if all of your values are passing through correctly; closest to the formula.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing  return type, and you probably want to use `Math.pow` -

```
// add the type - "double"
private double certificate;

// specify the signature.
public double compute_cert(int years, double amount, double rate) 
{
  certificate = amount * Math.pow(1 + rate / 100, years);
  return certificate;
}
```